# Using cJSON in windows

Tags: c, json, cjson

I want to use cJSON library on windows with clion. I have copied cJSON.h and cJSON.c to my project directory. I have included cJSON.h with this command: #include "cJSON.h"
When I try to compile my project, I get these errors:

```
CMakeFiles\Client.dir/objects.a(main.c.obj): In function `parse':
.../main.c:117: undefined reference to `cJSON_Parse@4'
.../main.c:121: undefined reference to `cJSON_GetErrorPtr@0'
.../main.c:127: undefined reference to `cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive@8'
.../main.c:128: undefined reference to `cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive@8'
.../main.c:131: undefined reference to `cJSON_IsString@4'
.../main.c:131: undefined reference to `cJSON_IsString@4'
.../main.c:141: undefined reference to `cJSON_Delete@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\Client.dir\build.make:84: recipe for target 'Client.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [Client.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Client.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Client.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Client.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Client.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Client' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Client] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem. The only thing I needed to do was to add cJSON.h and cJSON.c to the add_executable function of CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
add_executable(ProjectName main.c cJSON.h cJSON.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you did not add the `cjson.c` file to your build and this cause the link errors you get, or you may add c files (`cjson.c`) to c++ project, and you are missing 'extern C' prefix at your `cjson.h` header.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `CMakeLists.txt` file, under `set(SOURCE_FILES)` you should add the `cJson` files if not already present together with your own. Something like:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp include/main.h src/cJson.c include/cJson.h)
```

If that doesn't work or if they are already present you can try writing `extern C {...}` with the whole `cJson.h` content between the parenthesis if you are trying to use a C library with C++

Comment: Since I'm using c and all the files are in the same directory, I changed your set command and I get the same errors: set(SOURCE_FILES main.c cJSON.c cJSON.h)